# Mathematical logic question from Rosen book

Tags: logic

I am working through the Rosen Discrete Mathematics book. The question is;
M(x,y) = x has sent y an email message
Use quantifiers to express;
There are 2 students in your class who have sent each other email messages. 
My answer was this;

```
 \exists x  \exists y( (x \neq y)  \wedge M(x,y) \wedge M(y,x))
```

The book has the correct answer as;

```
 \exists x  \exists y( x \neq y  \rightarrow ( M(x,y) \wedge M(y,x)))
```

Use (http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) to convert the Latex
What I don't get is with their answer if x = y (same person) then wouldn't the proposition be true because (F -> ?) = T

Comment: Rosen's answer is incorrect: the text sentence clearly makes a claim of existence of at least two distinct people, but his formula does not. It is satisfied with x=y=a, where a is any student, even if nobody emailed anybody. To make a claim of existence one needs conjunction as in your formula. In fact, natural language sentences are almost never correctly formalized by a conditional under existential quantifiers, because if one means to assert existence material conditional can not accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The answer from the book is a statement that is true for any set with at least one element.

Comment: Excellent, I thought I was missing something important.